# Value of $A=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization

What is the value of $A=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^{n-1}}$?

By trial and error I can see that $0.6<A<0.7$, e.g. the sum of the first four terms is about 0.626.

I guess $A\approx 0.626$. Could anyone find $A$ analytically?

The terms of the series begin with 2 in denominator and n goes to infinity. I faced this problem when I wanted to optimize following sum for its maximum possible value:

S=1/a+1/b^2 + 1/ c^3 . . .< 1

where a, b, c ... must be intgers.

I found that :

1- for s to be maximum; a, b , ... must be subsequent values of natural numbers and it must start with 2 i.e. a=2, b=3, c=4    etc.

2 - The maximum value is about 0.626... that is the value of the sum of this series never reach 1.

Comment: Which variable is the limit taken over, going towards what? What are the bounds of the summation? What do the weird brackets mean?

Comment: Write it in proper Latex format.

Comment: Who knows what you actually mean (I agree with lavkush: you've already been a member of the site for three months. Time to learn a little MathJax)  , but if it is $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{n-1}}\;$ then the sum is clearly greater than one...

Comment: @sirous I don't know if you mean this edit. Please check it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^{n-1}} \sum_{n = 2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^{-1}\cdot n^n} = \sum_{n = 2}^{+\infty}\frac{n}{n^n} = \sum_{n = 2}^{+\infty} n^{1-n}$$

If your series starts from $n = 0$, the first term is zero. ($0^1$).

If your series started from $n = 1$, the first term would be $1$ ($1^0$).

Then you can conclude for the moment that

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{+\infty}n^{1-n} = \left(\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}n^{1-n}\right) - 1$$

Now recalling the famous Sophomore's dream #1:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} n^{-n} = \int_0^1 x^{-x}\ \text{d}x$$

and you can use it in your series:

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{+\infty} n^{1-n} = \int_0^1 x^{1-x} = 0.628474(...)$$

Which is the exact value of the series you have:

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{n-1}} = 0.628474(...)$$

**Sophomore's Dream with proof**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream

Comment: I don't understand how you got that step ("and you can use it in your series:")

Comment: @AritraDas I took the Sophomore's Dream (read the Wikipedia article) and I used it for the OP's series.

Comment: I know Sophomore's Dream. I'm asking how you went from $$\sum n^{-n} = \int x^{-x} dx$$ to $$\sum n^{1-n} = \int x^{1-x} dx$$.

Comment: @AritraDas It's easy to prove in the same way you prove SD. I did it by hand, I left it apart because anyone can prove it :)

Comment: @AritraDas Also, you need the extrema in the series and in the Integral, otherwise it doesn't hold in general.

Comment: Okay, then I'll try it once too. Thanks, cheers!

Comment: The reslt does not match with elementary calculations I mentioned in question. You can try and see that the sum of the first 3 terms is aaout 0.711... How can you claim the addition of other terms decrease the sum to 0.623...?

Comment: @sirous Then your calculation is wrong, because mine is correct.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for your analytic solution.